# Is it better to set an object value in a function, or return a value from a function?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

Lets say I have an array of data, and I want to process some function that will add or amend data in this array. e.g.

```
$my_data = array(
    'val1' => 'my value 1',
    'val2' => 'my value 2'
);
```

Traditionally I would pass the array or value to a function and return some data, e.g.

```
$my_data['val1'] = $this->get_new_var($my_data['val1']);
```

Well I just started doing something different which I think is better... I create the array within the $this object, like so (I am using Expression Engine):-

```
$this->EE->my_data = $my_data;
```

Then I just call a set method (rather than get) which does not need to return a value, because it sets the value within the function, e.g.

```
$this->set_new_var();
```

And within the set_new_var() function I can call the $this->EE->my_data array and manipulate it and set it as follows:

```
$this->EE->my_data['val1'] = $my_new_var;
```

So this seems to me to be cleaner, no need to pass variables to and from functions.

It also means I can set multiple values within the set function if need be, instead of returning one value from a function (or passing the entire the array and returning that).

So my question is, whether this set() method would be considered better, or should I stick to a traditional get() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my own opinion, a `set()` method allows me to handle the input in my own way and operate upon it, i.e. I can sanitize the input according to my use case and only pass on clean filtered input values to my function. Moreover, the `set()` method can be used to do more than just setting the variable. For example, in a particular use case, I may want to run a particular method or a process or even a delayed job, whenever a new value is set for a given variable (OOP). The `set()` method can be used to do exactly that, everytime. No need to repeat all your statements everytime such a behaviour is expected.

But, this is my own opinion.

Comment: the more I am changing my code to a set() method on an object, the more I am reducing code by making various objects already created available in other methods without having to pass variables bewteen them or make new database calls to get data.